# Error: Cannot find module 'loopback' in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, loopbackjs, loopback

I am facing below issue and unable to figure out the root cause.

> Error: Cannot find module 'loopback'

Below are the dependencies I have in my package.json

```
"loopback": "^3.19.0",
"loopback-boot": "^2.6.5",
"loopback-component-explorer": "^6.0.0",
"loopback-connector-postgresql": "^2.9.0"
```

First I did `npm i` and then `node .`

But it throws an error `Cannot find module 'loopback'`

Don't understand why this is behaving differently. Please suggest

Edit: My all modules are found under

```
    > node_modules
      > .staging
        > //loopback modules and other modules are placed under .staging but not sure why.
```

Comment: But it is in your node_modules directory right?

Comment: Yes it's there. bu modules are placed under node_modules >> .staging >> here modules are placed under .staging

Comment: Strange... sadly I have never worked with loopback but I know for certain it would help if you somehow provided a minimal project so people can work on it ^.^ BTW: I'm working on `electron` and `WebSocket` apps with node.js and those are definitely not in a ".staging" dir

Comment: I quickly ran `npm init -y && npm install loopback --save`and my loopback, loopback-connector, etc are not in a ".staging" folder.

Answer (score 4):

The fact that your dependencies are inside the staging directory and not the main node_modules directory imply that something went wrong with the download/installation process and your dependencies are not installed properly. And hence you get the 'Could not find module' error.

Try the following steps -

1. Delete package-lock.json
2. Delete Node Modules folder
3. Do a `npm install` to install packages listed in package.json

Once the installation is complete, all your node dependencies should be inside your node_modules folder.

It might also be worth checking to see if you have more than one node version on your machine. That could cause similar problems as well.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
npm config set user 0
npm config set unsafe-perm true

npm install -g loopback-cli
npm install
```

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/